# Where does the getLastLocation() gets location coordinates from?

Tags: android, gps, location

As per android documentation getLastLocation() provides last known location of the device. which means

1. Does getLastLocation() fetch the location details which are already stored in the Device? if so,
2. How that location is stored in device? Is any service continuously running in device to get the up to date location?

Thank you.

Comment: any time you open google maps or there is another app/service that requests a location it will update that last location

Comment: 1.May i Know where is that last location stored in devise? 2. What if I don't have any other app other app which requests for location? In that case will my last location be null?